# Highchart angular overflows container

Tags: css, angularjs, highcharts

I've created a directive for Angular 1.x to use Highcharts following instructions from Highcharts website. The chart is drawn with no errors, however, I can't find a way to make it fit the parent container. Most solutions point to using `#container` width, but I don't have said `#container` since it's a directive. Charts are massively overflowing.

I've got three columns created with `flex` and want each chart to fill 100% width of each of these columns.

How do I do that in Highcharts?

Comment: ok, I found the solution and it's a prosaic one: I needed to set display property on my container, however, that will only work with set width. I want the graph to use all available space of the container that doesn't have a set width. is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have an example what you are trying to do? Highcharts on load fills the whole container if the width is not defined. It will also resize on window.resize, for other cases you can use [chart.reflow](http://jsfiddle.net/q8xe7qLp/). There is also an open ticket on github regarding flex - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6427

Comment: yes, it works if I set the width of container. which is the name of the directive in html5 document. works ok

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the solution and it's a prosaic one: I needed to set display property on my container